# how to stretch background image in IE in BuddyPress child theme

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, background, buddypress

I’m building my own child theme, based on the BuddyPress default theme. I need to have a background image that’s stretched 100% width/height. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in the latest version of IE, the image just sits in the center, at its original size. No stretching takes place. Here is the CSS I’m using, which is just an augmentation of the parent theme (BP default theme):

```
body {
background-color: #000000;
background-image: url(images/DSC09005cc.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
background-attachment: fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
color: #555;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
line-height: 170%;
max-width: 1250px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 95%;
}
```

Thank you in advance.
Dima

Answer (score 0):

IE9+ supports the CSS3 background-size:cover feature but IE8 and lower does not. If you're trying to fix this for IE 8 and lower I might suggest something like:

HTML:

```
<body>
     <img src="images/DSC09005cc.jpg" class="fit-background">
...
```

CSS:

```
img.fit-background {
     min-height: 100%;
     min-width: 1024px;
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
     img.fit-background {
          left: 50%;
          margin-left: -512px;
     }
}

...
```

You could place the image in an IE conditional statement if you want to hide the image from browsers other than IE 6, 7 and 8:

```
<body>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <img src="images/DSC09005cc.jpg" class="fit-background">
<![endif]-->

...
```

Here's the original link if you want to read more about it and a couple of other options: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/